# Usage of environment variables inside obfuscar configuration files

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, obfuscar

Is it possible to use environment variables (for example those defined inside .csproj file) inside obfuscar configuration files? And if so, where can I find some documentation on the topic?

Tried to find some info about it on the Internet and failed.